# Can I access one of my case options from within my switch statement in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, switch-statement

I want to know if there is a way to access one of the case options from within another case option of the same switch statement:

For example:

```
puts "do you want [1], [2], [3], or [quit]?"
choice = gets.chomp

while choice != 'quit'

    case choice

    when '1' 
        puts "you chose one!"

    when '2'
        puts "you chose two!"

    when '3'
        puts "do you wish you had chosen two? [yes] [no] "
        answer = gets.chomp
        if answer == "yes"
            # how do I access my case choice when '2' ???
        else 
            puts "you are happy with three!"
        end
    end

end
```

Answer (score 1):

Turn the case clause into a function:

```
def chooser(choice)
  case choice
  when '1'
    # your case clauses ...
  when '3'
    # ...
    if answer == 'yes'
      chooser(2)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: would the puts statement I just added run? I'm not sure if you can see the edit yet, but all I did was add `puts "will this code run?"` directly under `chooser(2)`. I only ask since it's within the case block and I'm not too sure about them.

Comment: I tested it and it didn't run, is there a way to have whatever other code is written under `chooser("2")` to still run?

Answer (score 0):

You have many choices.  Here's another:

```
answer = "no way, Jose"

loop do
  if answer == "yes"
    answer = "nope"
    choice = '2'
  else    
    puts "do you want [1], [2], [3], or [quit]?"
    choice = gets.chomp
  end

  case choice
  when '1'
    puts "you chose one!"
  when '2'
    puts "you chose two!"
  when '3'
    puts "do you wish you had chosen two? [yes] [no] "
    answer = gets.chomp
    puts "you are happy with three!" unless answer == "yes"
  when 'quit'
    break   
  end
end
```